# Through model in Django

Tags: python, django-models

I am getting errors while I am building the following database. Idea is that you create a Team object. Create Student Objects and link them to Teams. And then give the Students points through PointEntry objects. I want to relate the team given to each Student object in each PointEntry Object. But for some reason, Django gives the error:

score_board.Student: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'score_board.PointEntry.team', but it does not have a foreign key to 'PointEntry' or 'Team'.

Modeladmin Class

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'team']
    list_filter = ['team']
class PointEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    list_display = ['student', 'points'] 
    list_filter = ['student']
```

Below are the models

```
class Team(models.Model):
    # Team/group model
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Student(models.Model):
    # Student model
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class PointEntry(models.Model):
    # Point entry's made by users appointed to a student in a group
    student = models.OneToOneField(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField()
    team = models.ManyToManyField(Team, through='Student')
```

Comment: You can only use a `through` model in a `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: If I do that, I get the following error, I've tried this as well: ```<class 'score_board.admin.PointEntryAdmin'>: (admin.E109) The value of 'list_display[3]' must not be a ManyToManyField.
score_board.Student: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by'score_board.PointEntry.team', but it does not have a foreign key to 'PointEntry' or 'Team'.```

-- edited the question to reflect your comment.

Comment: that is because in a `ModelAdmin`, you can indeed not add a `ManyToManyField` to the `list_display`. So the problem is not the *model*, but its modeladmin.

Comment: If I remove 'team' from the modeladmin, It looks like this:

```
class PointEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['student', 'points']
    list_filter = ['student']
```
This still results in: 
`
score_board.Student: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'score_board.PointEntry.team', but it does not have a foreign key to 'PointEntry' or 'Team'.
`

Comment: Edited the question to reflect your comment.

Comment: If you use `Student` as a `through` model, it should, as the error says, have two `ForeignKey`s to the two models, so one to the `PointEntry`, and one to the `Team`.

Comment: I cannot add a `ForeignKey PointEntry` to `Student` because PointEntry is defined lower.

Even in NL:
Misschien is het makkelijker als ik uitleg wat ik probeer: Denk aan Zwijnstein van Harry Potter. De founders maken de huizen, en de studenten komen aan en worden ingedeeld in een Team. Ik wil dan zodra een docent punten geeft via Point Entry, dat ie alleen de student hoeft te benoemen en dat het 'Team' automatisch opgehaald wordt via het Student Object. Maar ik kan die niet zomaar aanroepen omdat het allemaal "foreignKeys" objecten zijn.

Waardeer de hulp enorm! Zit hier al 4 uur aan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your through model needs a `ForeignKey` to both models. Since the model that defines the `ManyToManyField` is defined lower, you can not reference to the class. But in Django, you can also use a string literal:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pointentry = models.ForeignKey('PointEntry', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class PointEntry(models.Model):
    # Point entry's made by users appointed to a student in a group
    student = models.OneToOneField(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField()
    team = models.ManyToManyField(Team, through='Student')
```

Django will then replace the string with a reference to the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
      class Team(models.Model):
      # Team/group model
     name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
      student = models. models.ManyToManyField(Student,through='PointEntry ')


  class Student(models.Model):
   # Student model
name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
team = models. models.ManyToManyField(Team,through='PointEntry')

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name}"

 class PointEntry(models.Model):
# Point entry's made by users       appointed to a student in a group
  student = models.  ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  team = models. ForeignKey(Team,   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  points = models.IntegerField()
```

I think a model like this might work for what you’re trying to achieve.